# How to disable NSDocument's window title popup

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument

I have an NSDocument based app with autosave enabled.

I'd like to prevent this popup from showing: [image: autosave popup]

I have tried returning nil from NSWindow's –title, –representedFilename and –representedURL which hide the title effectively hide the title but have no effect on the downward facing disclosure indicator and the popup.

Is there a way I can prevent this popup from being presented?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to prevent the button from being shown by overriding NSWindow's

`+ (NSButton *)standardWindowButton:(NSWindowButton)windowButtonKind forStyleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle`

and returning nil for `NSWindowDocumentVersionsButton`

Comment: You need to override that in NSWindow subclass, not in NSWindowController subclass! Dont make the same mistake as I did (:

Comment: This also disable x, minimize, enlarge buttons right? My app just got rejected because of this.

Comment: You should return nil only for NSWindowDocumentVersionsButton. If you return nil for every button, no button will be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Return false from NSDocument's autosavesInPlace() override

Comment: The first line of the question mentions that autosave is enabled. Disabling a feature to avoid showing the button is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a streamlined toolbar (wwdc2016)

```
  override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        self.view.window!.titleVisibility = .hidden  
  }
```

This removes also the title bar (but not the ones of tabbed windows)