# How to hide Open and Save document features in a Document Based application?

Tags: swift, macos, nsdocument

Like Safari app, in a macOS Swift project I would like to let users to open more than a window and possibly use tabbed browsing to switch from a window to another. The app starts with a blank window and don't need to save or open documents.

A Document Based application seems perfect to me for handle more than a window but I don't want users have to handle documents. How can I disable or hide, if possible, the Open and Save document features?

Edit: if possible, I would like to disable this popup also:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple - just remove (delete) the Open, Open Recent..., Save, Save as... menu items from the menu XIB. If you don't want a title bar, simply untick the "Title" checkbox for the window in the XIB, though that makes the window difficult to move.

[image]

If you have a title bar, to override "Untitled", you *could*

```
override var displayName: String! {
    get {
        return "Anything you like, even \"\""
    }
    set {

    }
}
```

however that would still allow access to the save as menu through the chevron. To suppress that, you need an `NSWindowDelegate` [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419465-window)

> window(_:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:)
>   Asks the delegate whether the window displays the title pop-up menu in response to a Command-click or Control-click on its title.

Comment: Hi Grimxn, thank you for the answer, do you know if there is the possibility to hide also the popup menu in the title bar? (I edited the question to include this)

Comment: `shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:` suppressed the right click path popup, not the chevron rename/move popup. [How to disable NSDocument's window title popup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40502619/4244136)

Answer (score 0):

Just add autosavesInPlace at true